# Qt5 QML 3D графика

Tags: c++, qt5, qml

Вот этот код написан на Qt 4.8:

```
import QtQuick 1.0
import Qr3D 1.0
import Qt3D.Shapes 1.0

Viewport{
  Mesh{
  id: carMesh
  source: "/home/use/car.3DS"
  }

  Item3D{
  mesh: carMesh
  }
}
```

Как точно такой же код написать на современном Qt 5.10?

Т.е. вывести 3d модель на экран?

Comment: попробуй перенести модель в другие форматы (• FBX
• Collada (dae)
• OBJ
• Blender (blend)
• GLTF2 ) я бы в формат .obj перевёл